# Antd Popover close only when click on a button

Tags: popover, antd

Here is [sandbox Antd pop over](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmrq7q22q0)

As you can see in the example when you click out side anywhere, [popover](https://ant.design/components/popover/) automatically closed. I want to disable that thing and close it only through  click on a button. 
I don't see such options in [Popover](https://ant.design/components/popover/) and [Tooltip](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API) apis.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this you need to remove your `onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}` method. You can call `this.handleVisibleChange` function on button click as given below:

```
<Popover
    content={<a onClick={this.hide}>Close</a>}
    title="Title"
    trigger="click"
    visible={this.state.visible}
  >
    <Button onClick={this.handleVisibleChange} type="primary">Click me</Button>
</Popover>
```

I have created a working example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4829z0lmy).

Comment: Thanks alot @Triyugi Narayan Mani

Comment: How to use trigger="focus" then?